# Is it possible to see all feedbacks on a Freelancer when not logged in?

Tags: odesk

For example on this [Freelancer public profile](https://www.odesk.com/o/profiles/users/_~01497b2b5704a183d7/) I can only see five feedbacks when not connected to my account, while I see ten feedbacks when I am.

[image: Five feedbacks example]

Does that mean that some feedbacks are not publicly available but restricted to oDesk users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to see all feedbacks on a freelancer when not logged in.